# Is it possible to use the modified returned reference in an overload like `int &operator[]'?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Suppose I have a class that implements an array of `int` which grows on demand. The class also implements the `int &operator[]` method overloading the `[]` operator and returning a reference to a value in the array.

Now I use the operator in a loop like this

```
classInstance[index] += 1;
```

I want to know whether it's possible to use the incremented value inside the `int &operator[]` function?

To make it clear, what I want is to be able to know what the new value of the referenced integer is in order to upadte the maximum and minimum values.

Comment: _"and do something after the returned reference is modified?"_ 1st part yes, second (cited) no. Use an explicit setter instead. Well you could have installed observers, but that's to broad without a properly given use case.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ what do you suggest? Is there something that one can do in this situation? Is there a design pattern that allows this or something similar?

Comment: Updated my 1st comment, depends on what you're delivering with `operator[]`, with `int` such won't work. You'll need to encapsulate it into another class. We've been doing such with a so called `Registry` (map) that allows to observe certain values contained being changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to solve this problem would be to return something that *pretends* to be an `int&`, while itself providing overloads for methods like `operator+=`, etc.

Something like this:

```
class MyIntReference {
 public:
  MyIntReference(int& reference_to_wrap) :
    wrapped_reference_{reference_to_wrap}
  {}

  // this method returns void, but you could have it return whatever you want
  void operator+=(const int addend) {
    wrapped_reference_ += addend;
    DoWhateverYouWant();
  }

 private:
  int& wrapped_reference_;
}

// then, in your other class
MyIntReference YourOtherClass::operator[](const int index) {
  return MyIntReference{my_array_[index]};
}
```

Obviously, this is just a rough piece of code, but I think it could be refined into something quite nice.

Comment: I know I saw a comment and an upvote lying around here somewhere, but they seem to have disappeared... I need to keep a closer eye on that cat.

Comment: What is this syntax `wrapped_reference_{reference_to_wrap}` can you point me to an online resource where it's explained?

Comment: @iharob Sure! It's a one-item constructor initialization list, and I think it's explained pretty well [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/101-constructor-initialization-lists/). The example in the link uses parentheses instead of braces, but either one works in this case.

Comment: I mean how are braces valid in this situation.

Comment: @iharob I'm using uniform initialization syntax instead of parenthesis syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Execute-Around Pointer idiom](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Execute-Around_Pointer) . Your `operator[]` would need to return a proxy object of a class that implements the necessary operations. Then you could "do something" in the destructor of the proxy object or immediately after the operations in their implementations.